# AGIC deployment with multiple AKS clusters and single App Gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, ingress-controller

AGIC brownfield deployment, 2 AKS clusters and common (shared) App Gateway. Both clusters having the exact same Ingress and Service definitions.
This resulted in a single rule and a single backend pool in the app gw, while there should've been obviously two rules and two backend pools (one of each for each of the two clusters).

Production Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: services-recruitment-api-prod
  namespace: services-recruitment
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/hostname-extension: "prod-XXX.XXX.XX"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: "prod-XXX.XXX.XX"
spec:
  ingressClassName: azure-application-gateway
  rules:
  - host: prod-XXX.XXX.XX
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /Recruitment/swagger/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: recruitment-api-s
            port:
              number: 80
```

[image]

Dev Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: services-recruitment-api
  namespace: services-recruitment
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/hostname-extension: "dev-XXX.XXX.XX"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: "dev-XXX.XXX.XX"
spec:
  ingressClassName: azure-application-gateway
  rules:
  - host: dev-XXX.XXX.XX
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /Recruitment/swagger/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: recruitment-api-s
            port:
              number: 80
```

[image]

APP GATEWAY:
AGIC created for the same backend pool two rules but with one target which pointed to IP address of the second AKS cluster.
[image]

**If there is any way to somehow add prefix or rename backend pool using annotations?** Because whatever will be done manually on App Gateway level, will be overridden by AGIC automatically.

Comment: Use unique hostnames for each AKS cluster in your Ingress definitions. This will naturally create separate routing rules in the Application Gateway. If using unique hostnames is not feasible, consider using unique path-based routing for each cluster. AFAIK, AGIC does not support annotations to directly rename backend pools. However, AGIC is an evolving project, and it's worth checking the latest [AGIC documentation](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/) for any new features or annotations that might support this functionality.

Comment: I'm already using unique value for appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/hostname-extension and  host name in spec section, but AGIC still use the same backend pool. Looks like it uses backend pool naming convention which consist of  POD_NAME-SERVICE_NAME-PORT

Comment: Moreover adding appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: "prod-aks.example.com" and appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname:"dev-aks.example.com" did not fix the issue.  App gateway still has one backend pool with one target (IP address)

Comment: Can you kindly share your code body, and your AGIC configuration details once?

Comment: Updated the post with screenshots

Comment: Thanks, let me see what I can find on this meanwhile you can check this out to verify your brownfield deployment- https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/setup/install-existing/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/what-does-it-mean-for-the-application-gateway-ingress-controller/ba-p/2839051